# Limit duration of waterfall display in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome developer tools' network panel to see how long it is taking to get various responses.  I don't need or want to reload the web page, so after a while, the waterfall display is showing data for tens of minutes or more.  This makes the response times hard to see.  Is there a way to have the waterfall display only show the last N minutes of data?

I looked on google, and found lots of basic tutorial about using dev tools, but nothing this detailed.  I also tried looking through the various menus in Chrome but did not find anything that looked useful.

Comment: Not implemented. You can open a feature request on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Request filed.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1040211